# My VS 2022 Windows Form app will not run on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm not sure what's going on here, the app runs on my laptop outside the development environment but will not run on Windows Server 2012 R2, absolutely no errors are generated, just doesn't load the form.  I used the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 to create the application, application settings are:

Output Type: Windows Application
Target Framework: .NET 6.0
Target OS: Windows
Target OS Version: 8.0
Supported OS Version: 7.0 (tried 8.0 as well)
Target CPU: x64

The are a lot of other settings I believe are not applicable so I don't list them here.  The permissions on the server are set properly.  When I delete the app.dll file, the exe complains it can't find it so I know at least the exe "should" run.  I get no error messages, nothing in the logs.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I take it, you have written logs on form load? Does the form load Event happen at all?

Comment: Yes, I write to logs when an error occurs, nothing in the logs.  I'll try writing out to the logs when the forms loads, error or no.  Maybe that'll shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Write to a log as the first line in form load, and regularly after that. Make sure that something is happening!

Comment: Modified the app to write to the log, it's the first line in the `Form1_Load` event, nothing in the log.

Comment: Would even consider if you can, write a log entry before and after calling the main form.  May need to tinker with app events.  If you're not already, maybe add logging in the Unhandled exception handler

Comment: I have log entries in all events up until the `Form1_Load`, I used this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 to get the order of events.  Nothing in the logs.

Comment: Handle the events of the application itself, not just the startup form. There is a button to view application events in the project properties.

Comment: I'm looking at my project's properties via Project->project name Properties and I see no "events" button.  Where exactly would that be?

Comment: Silly question, but I presume .Net 6 is installed on the Server?

Comment: have a look in server event viewer. dotnet events are collected in application log.

Comment: Nothing in any logs any where, server or otherwise.  Yes, .NET 6 is installed.

Comment: Have you checked if your antivirus is stopping your program from running? Did you install your program or merely copy the files?

Comment: The Anti-Virus is not interfering with the program,  Good suggestion though, hadn't thought of that one.

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: [Install .NET on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70#install-the-runtime), [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), and [Single-file deployment and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?source=recommendations&tabs=vs#publish-a-single-file-app).